# Unix select system call in Rust

Tags: unix, rust

I have a list of file descriptors and I want to find what all are ready to read. So far I was doing it python using below function
`select.select(read_fds, [], [], 1)` and it returns list of ready to read streams.
The same thing I am trying to do in Rust. I am using nix crate but there the function [select](http://quodlibetor.github.io/tabin-plugins/doc/nix/sys/select/fn.select.html)  only returns the number of file descriptors ready to read. Is there a way to get the list of file descriptors also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is a C function which modifies the arguments you pass to it (the file descriptor sets) in-place, rather than allocating and returning an entirely new structure. `nix::select` is just a thin wrapper for that C function. Python is really the outlier here, as it deviates from the C API by allocating entirely separate lists containing the results.

When using `nix::select`, you should check the FD sets you pass in - they will have been modified to contain only the ready file descriptors.

```rust
let mut readfds = FdSet::new();
readfds.insert(0);
readfds.insert(3);
let _ = select(&mut readfds, None, None)
for fd in readfds.fds(None) {
    println!("{:?}", fd);
}
```

[`FdSet::fds`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.19.0/nix/sys/select/struct.FdSet.html#method.fds) returns an iterator over the file descriptors in the set.